# Variable inside a foreach doesn't accesible in scope and service

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller something like that:

```
qApiService.getField()
.then(function(data) {
    $scope.data.current = data;
    //...
    //...
    $scope.arrayFieldsDisplay.forEach(function(entry) {
        var val = $metaData.arrayCollectionFieldsDisplay[entry];

        var jsonSend = {
            "atQ":$scope.data.current.atQ,
            "anQ":$scope.data.current.anQ,
            "cxSe":$scope.data.current.cxSe,
            "qN":entry,
            "qA":val,
        };

        if (val !== null && val !== 'null' && typeof val !== 'undefined') {
            qApiService.colField(jsonSend)
            .then(function(data) {
                $scope.data.current = data;
            });
        }
    });
```

If you check the code, u can see the "$scope.data.current" variable is set in the top code for initialize it, and set the same "$scope.data.current" inside of "qApiService.colField".

I'm trying to use that variable when i'm iterating the "$scope.arrayFieldsDisplay" array.

My question: why when i set scope.data.current inside the foreach is not accessible in the next loop or scope parent? Is always the same value to scope.data.current.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by not accessible? Is data undefined? Is current undefined?

Comment: Do you mean that the second iterationof the forEach loop doesn't see the value set by the instruction `$scope.data.current = data;`of the first iteration? This instruction is executed asynchronously, when the `qApiService.colField(jsonSend)` promise is resolved, so that's not surrising.

Comment: Thanks for ur comments. Yes the problem was about promise service. I need to update my code to solve that. Thank u again!